# Strange regexp match error in Sphinx

Tags: regex, sphinx

I was trying to map start times for shows in my db from the various notations to houram/pm so I made a regexp_filter:

```
regexp_filter = ([0-9]|10|11|12)( a|a)(.)?(m)(.)? =>\1am
```

which seemed to be working well with a query

```
select  ID,Name from idx_Table WHERE (MATCH('"8am"'))
```

but all of a sudden I keep getting

```
[Err] 1064 - index idx_Table: syntax error, unexpected $end near ''
```

If I remove the " from the query and do

```
select  ID,Name from idx_Table WHERE (MATCH('8am'))
```

it works.

If I change the "am" to "AM" and keep the quotes

```
select  ID,Name from idx_Table WHERE (MATCH('"8AM"'))
```

it works (???) which is strange since as far as I know Sphinx is not case-sensitive.

Lastly if I comment out the regex_p it works. Any thoughts as I am officially stumped.

Update:
Thinking somehow the " in the query was introducing errors I then removed them, however now the errors I get is

[Err] 1064 - index idx_Tabke: syntax error, unexpected '/' near '/2 (disclosure)

So something in the regex_p seems to be introducing a character that sphinx does not like?

Comment: Dunno the source of your error, but you realize that `(.)` matches any character (and the parentheses are superfluous)?  I would phrase that `([0-9]|1[0-2]) ?a\.?m\.?`

Comment: Holy Newbie Mistake Batman! Thank you I was tearing my hair out after making so much progress can't believe I missed something that basic. Thank you! Can I vote up a comment?

Comment: You should be able to, although it doesn't particularly register anywhere useful. (Not sure at which privilege level you need to be.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the dot match at the end 'swallows' any char after the 'am'. So in your case the " is 'removed' from the query. If do want to remove something, be more specific so as not to match "

Also sphinx IS case sensitive, its just normal to setup charset_table to not be. regexes are case sensitive too, which is why AM was not replaced.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that and had in fact followed on of your suggestions from another answer to force acronyms to be upper_Acronym with regexp_filter in the index. However I still cannot find a charset_table in my config or a separate .txt file. Is there some default behavior inherent in Sphinx that need to be overridden then via an explicit charset?